# Get image value of item which is clicked in datalist by Javascript and display like jquery fancy

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:DataList ID="Images" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="4"  runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Images_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imagess" Height="180" Width="175" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

this is the Datalist and i bind it image , i want if i clicked in any image in image items in datalist i want to display like fancy jquery

Comment: fancy jquery? is that a plugin or are you saying jquery is fancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can use ClientId to get exact ID and then bind the event like following.

```
$("#<%=Images.ClientID %>").on("click", "img", function () {
            // do something fancy with the clicked image.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ClientIDMode="Static"` property to ensure a static id on the `DataList`. Then, use `jQuery` `.on()` to handle the `click` for images within.

Specify `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the `DataList` control.

```
<asp:DataList ID="Images" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

Using `jQuery`

```
$("#Images").on("click", "img", function() {     
    // do something fancy with the clicked image.
});
```